# How to get path of Android shared Directories in internal/primary storage not SD card?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, android-file, android-external-storage

I want to show android file system just like file browser and want to show shared folder path so that if someone download some stuff in that folder then that data persist even after uninstall of my app.

Here is what I am using:

```
file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

This try to return path from SD card, and don't work if there is no sdcard mounted.

So I want to know that how can I show the downloads directory or other shared directory path that is on my device or on emulator without an sd card. 
I saw this function:

```
public static File getDownloadCacheDirectory ();
```

But i think this is just a cache directory and not actual download directory.

I am using astro file manager on my device which don't have SD card. In astro file manager when I click on `Downloads` directory, it first show `mnt/sdcard/Downloads` for a moment in address bar and then go to internal path similar to `[Flash/sd card storage icon]/Primary/Downloads`. So I want to know that how I can get that primary path in case external storage is not available?

Please let me know how I can do that or else point me towards some good resource where I can find about it.

Comment: Please edit your question to replace `somepath` with **the actual value**.

Comment: @CommonsWare actually that is not path but an icon. probably also representing sd card , so I guess it is showing location inside sd card. Sorry for confusion. but point is that my device actually don't have sdcard actually.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you think that in my device sdcard is emulated and I need to emulate that into AVD/emulator as well ?

Comment: I think that very few modern Android devices have [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) be on removable media. I cannot even name a single device that does not have external storage as part of the on-board flash, though presumably there are some such devices. SD cards are treated as [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). I don't know what "dont work" means. You might try calling `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to see what it returns.